# Angular, click function on outside of directive to fire one inside

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to set up a click function on the outside of the directive to change something in the inside. It seems it's easy to pass a click function outwards, however i need an event outside of the directive to call a function inside of it to update something.

So I have a click function outside the directive

```
  $scope.clickOutisde = function(){
    //fire event inside
 }
```

I want to pass it in (I guess)

```
  scope: {
      updateFn: '='
  }
```

And on the directive itself

```
 update-fn="clickOutisde"
```

And inside the directive controller

```
  $scope.updateFn = function(){
    console.log("hit!");
  }
```

So the intended effect is I would click function on the outside which would cause a function inside the directive controller to fire. I know it's a bit of a weird set up - but I'm wondering if something like this is possible (as this is not working). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The straightforward way to achieve what you want is using `emit/broadcast` and I try to steer clear from those as much as possible.

What you can do, is have a wrapper object with a boolean inside and change its value every time the function is triggered, and have that wrapper object passed to the directive and keep watch on it:

**Controller + Directive:**

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            functionWrapper: "="
        },
        template: 'inside directive',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            scope.$watch(function() {
                return scope.functionWrapper.flag;
            }, function(newVal, oldVal) {
                console.log('function fired');
            });
        }
    }
});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.functionWrapper = { flag : false };
    $scope.func = function () {
        console.log('firing in controller');
        $scope.functionWrapper.flag = !$scope.functionWrapper.flag;
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div my-directive function-wrapper="functionWrapper"></div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/12997/)